# Vagrant - cannot log into my Box

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I created a Vagrant Box, played with it, made some custom dev.

But then I wanted to login without playing "vagrant ssh myvagrantbox".

For that I appended the  "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" from my host to the autorised keys of myvagrantbox. 
Then I made a "Vagrant halt" / "vagrant up".

But now Vagrant says it cannot connect because of a timeout. 
Vagrant says "myvagrantbox" is running but I can't connect with "vagrant ssh myvagrantbox".

Any idea ? 
A better solution than destroying, beginning from zero again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable the GUI mode, as your box might be stuck at the bootloader.

For this just add this to your `Vagrantfile` :

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
  vb.gui = true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete what I wanted to do:

I wanted to connect to my Vagrant box with ssh, without playing "vagrant ssh myvagrantbox".

The solution was quite simple:
ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 -i ~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key

Vagrant uses ssh by default on port 2222 and not port 22. I was forgotting the port and was stuck with a password.

Hopes this will help someday...